# php, highlight search keywords without breaking anchor tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, simple-html-dom

I already did a search on Google and Stackoverflow, but I couldn't find any solution that works for me.

This is what I have so far:

```
$string = preg_replace('/'.$keyword.'/i', 
'<span class="highlight">$0</span>', $string);
```

Which works fine, except when the string contains anchor tags. But I still want to be able to highlight the keywords outside and within the anchor tags.

Example:

```
$keyword = 's';
```

Output:

I alrady did a **s**earch on [Google](http://google.com) and [**S**tackoverflow](/stackoverflow.com), but I couldn't find any **s**olution that work**s** for me.

I would appreciate it if someone could find a solution for this without having to use **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like you'll need to use a DOM parser as you are only wanting to deal with the "text" in your string, rather than the entire string. So you need a way to determine what is "text" and what are HTML attributes.

There are **lots** of examples of why regex doesn't work for trying to parse HTML.

Comment: Yes. "Please tell me how to solve this problem without using the technology which was developed to solve this problem because you can't do it without it"

Comment: @Colin... yah, funny, dude. I just don't wanna rely on someone else's library, especially a 1000 line code for a minor thing like that.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Haha. Nicely worded.

Comment: @krysis: It's not a minor thing. HTML isn't regular. You can't use regular expressions to pass it without things breaking (like you have noticed with it breaking with anchor tags). Use the tools that are built to solve the problem. If you need help on using a DOM parser then open another question.

Comment: It will only include anchor tags, and nothing else. <a href=""></a>, that's it, nothing else to it. Very irregular. But thanks anyway. I'll try to find a solution myself. I'm definitely not going to download Simple HTML DOM Parser.

Answer (score 2):

This should work in most situations:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(?![^<>]*>)'.preg_quote($keyword,"/").'/i', 
'<span class="highlight">$0</span>', $string);
```